# ISAPI extension timeout

Tags: timeout, isapi-extension

We want to specify a timeout for IIS requests reaching an ISAPI extension. I saw on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/e1f13641(v=vs.100) that there is an `executionTimeout` property. Is this only for ASP.NET or it is valid for ISAPI extensions, too? If it is valid for ISAPI, will reaching the timeout shut down only the request but also the whole dll? If it shuts down the whole dll: Does this trigger a callback function in the dll?

I googled a lot. I found different articles but did not see an answer to my question.